# Left join query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have problem with MySQL Database.

I have two tables.

**doTable_1**

```
+------+----------+
| AREA | REGISTER |
+------+----------+
| AAAA | YS       |
| BBBB | YS       |
| CCCC | YS       |
| DDDD | YS       |
| EEEE | YS       |
| FFFF | YS       |
+------+----------+
```

**doTable_2**

```
+--------------+------+---------------+
| PREMIUM_AREA | AREA | NAME_AREA     |
+--------------+------+---------------+
| ZZZ          | GGGG | AREA BLAWED   |
| ZZZ          | FFFF | AREA BAYWOOD  |
| ZZZ          | AAAA | AREA BILLFOLD |
| ZZZ          | BBBB | AREA BEACHED  |
| ZZZ          | CCCC | AREA BASED    |
| ZZZ          | DDDD | AREA BANED    |
| ZZZ          | EEEE | AREA BAWD     |
| ZZZ          | HHHH | AREA ARBORED  |
| ZZZ          | LLLL | AREA BLAND    |
| ZZZ          | MMMM | AREA YSENA    |
| ZZZ          | NNNN | AREA AIRSHED  |
| ZZZ          | PPPP | AREA ALLOD    |
| ZZZ          | QQQQ | AREA BEEYARD  |
+--------------+------+---------------+
```

I need this output, that join the two tables for field AREA to extract all rows :

```
+------+--------------+----------+
| AREA | PREMIUM_AREA | REGISTER |
+------+--------------+----------+
| AAAA | ZZZ          | YS       |
| BBBB | ZZZ          | YS       |
| CCCC | ZZZ          | YS       |
| DDDD | ZZZ          | YS       |
| EEEE | ZZZ          | YS       |
| GGGG | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| FFFF | ZZZ          | YS       |
| HHHH | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| LLLL | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| MMMM | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| NNNN | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| PPPP | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| QQQQ | ZZZ          | NULL     |
+------+--------------+----------+
```

And tried this query but the output is wrong, why?

```
mysql> SELECT
    AREA,
    PREMIUM_AREA,
    REGISTER
FROM
    `doTable_1` A
LEFT JOIN `doTable_2` CB ON A.AREA = CB.AREA
WHERE
    PREMIUM_AREA = 'ZZZ'
GROUP BY
    AREA
ORDER BY
    AREA ASC;
+------+--------------+----------+
| AREA | PREMIUM_AREA | REGISTER |
+------+--------------+----------+
| AAAA | ZZZ          | YS       |
| BBBB | ZZZ          | YS       |
| CCCC | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| DDDD | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| EEEE | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| GGGG | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| FFFF | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| HHHH | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| LLLL | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| MMMM | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| NNNN | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| PPPP | ZZZ          | NULL     |
| QQQQ | ZZZ          | NULL     |
+------+--------------+----------+
14 rows in set
```

Comment: tip: write table name in select clause. `A.Area, CB.premium_area, A.register` and try without `Group BY`

Comment: What you tried can not work. You must get syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `LEFT JOIN`, the first table must be the one that contains all the rows you want returned, and the second table is the one that can be missing rows. So it should be:

```
SELECT 
    A.AREA,
    PREMIUM_AREA,
    REGISTER
FROM
    `doTable_2` A
LEFT JOIN `doTable_1` CB ON A.AREA = CB.AREA
WHERE
    PREMIUM_AREA = 'ZZZ'
GROUP BY
    A.AREA
ORDER BY
    A.AREA ASC;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6a40/5)

Or you could keep the tables in the same order, and use `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the tables in the join clause, like this:

```
SELECT
    AREA,
    PREMIUM_AREA,
    REGISTER
FROM
    `doTable_2` A
LEFT JOIN `doTable_1` CB ON A.AREA = CB.AREA
WHERE
    PREMIUM_AREA = 'ZZZ'
ORDER BY
    AREA ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `right join`

```
SELECT
    AREA,
    PREMIUM_AREA,
    REGISTER
FROM
    `doTable_1` A
RIGHT JOIN `doTable_2` CB ON A.AREA = CB.AREA
WHERE
    PREMIUM_AREA = 'ZZZ'
GROUP BY
    AREA
ORDER BY
    AREA ASC;
```

or if you want to use `left join` swap the tables

```
SELECT 
    A.AREA,
    PREMIUM_AREA,
    REGISTER
FROM
    `doTable_2` A
LEFT JOIN `doTable_1` CB ON A.AREA = CB.AREA
WHERE
    PREMIUM_AREA = 'ZZZ'
GROUP BY
    A.AREA
ORDER BY
    A.AREA ASC;
```